# dotnet trace collect never properly starts within linux

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, trace

After running the trace command, it never reaches past printing out the Provider Names. It never reaches the actual lines which describe the process it is accessing & to which file it will output. It seems stuck starting up, and trying to close it using ctrl+c does not work.

My container runs a dotnet sdk 6 image (from mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim). To run commands within I accessed it using

```bash
docker exec -it <containerId> /bin/bash
```

then I installed dotnet trace using the following command

```bash
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-trace
```

and started to run a simple dotnet trace collect

```bash
dotnet trace collect --name <myAppName>
```

The output looked like the following:

```bash
No profile or providers specified, defaulting to trace profile 'cpu-sampling'

Provider Name                           Keywords            Level               Enabled By
Microsoft-DotNETCore-SampleProfiler     0x0000F00000000000  Informational(4)    --profile
Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime         0x00000014C14FCCBD  Informational(4)    --profile
```

Anyone ever had this issue on linux? The trace doesn't seem to properly start and you cannot even stop it using ctrl+c. I even tried running it outside of the docker container and yet the same issue occured were it never properly started.

*I tried the same procedure on windows, on which it properly ran the trace and I was able to properly stop it using ctrl+c.
A proper start would be indiciated by the output looking more like the following...*

```bash
No profile or providers specified, defaulting to trace profile 'cpu-sampling'

Provider Name                           Keywords            Level               Enabled By
Microsoft-DotNETCore-SampleProfiler     0x0000F00000000000  Informational(4)    --profile
Microsoft-Windows-DotNETRuntime         0x00000014C14FCCBD  Informational(4)    --profile

Process        : C:\Users\<pathToApplication>
Output File    : C:\Users\<pathToApplication>_<date>.nettrace
```

Comment: After running a dotnet stack report on the dotnet trace collect this is what I got. Appears it is waiting for something: blob:https://imgur.com/e7fe4ffa-269b-410c-ae16-c931ed0ba4f1